# How to make Hyper tread on in Ubuntu 15 linux

Tags: multi-core

What is terminal command to  make 'on' a hyperthread in Ubuntu?

Comment: Hmmm... do you mean the `--jobs` option for the `make` command?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run N concurrent jobs, where N is a number > 0, use:

```
make -j N
```

For example, for 4 concurrent jobs, use:

```
make -j 4
```

If you want to build so you have the same number of jobs as CPUs, use:

```
make -j $(nprocs)
```

You can also specify an "infinite" number (that is, maximized parallel jobs, which is not advised since it will spawn way too many concurrent jobs to be useful) using:

```
make -j
```

Comment: What about multi Tasking,and run multi Task simultaneously ? are the above commands different to do this job?:)